# Select ComboBox Item with only part of the Item

Tags: java, combobox

For a Java Schoolproject I would like to have a table from witch you can select a Item that then shows up on a new window. In that window you can change things like ComboBoxes and others. My only problem is, that I dont know how to select the Item of the ComboBox I need. All the ComboBoxItems are Objects and I dont know how to handle this.

My ComboBoxItem looks like this:

> Apprentice [person=Person, DB ID: 9, Kappa Kappa, Kappastrasse 21,
>   CityID: 4521, kappa.kappa@kappa.ch, idpersonen=9,
>   vertragsstart=2020-01-02, ausbildungsct=2, id=6]

Now, my Question is, how do I select the ComboBoxitem where the id=6, all the things I found needed the whole Object to select a special Item. How would you guys go at this problem?

Good luck and thanks for the Help.
Bono

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All I had to do was a really simple while with a for and a if.

```
int trys = 0;
  while (0 == apprenticeComboBoxZeugnis.getItemCount() && trys < 10000) {
    System.out.println(apprenticeComboBoxZeugnis.getItemCount());
    for (int i = 0; i < apprenticeComboBoxZeugnis.getItemCount(); i++) {
      apprenticeComboBoxZeugnis.setSelectedIndex(i - 1);
      int spacko = getApprenticeCombo();
      if (spacko == lehrlingsid) {
        TableFilterListenerZeugnis tableFilterListenerZeugnis = new TableFilterListenerZeugnis(
            this);
        tableFilterListenerZeugnis.updateNoten();
        break;
      }
    }
    trys++;
  }
```

This first trys until the number of Objects is not = 0 and after that looks at every object, cuts out the id with getApprenticeCombo() and compares it with my id I allready have. If they match it breaks out and is done with it.